# htaccess add RedirectMatch 301 rules

Tags: .htaccess

i add this rules to my .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /wp-content/my-image-5x5.jpg /wp-content/default-5x5.jpg
```

Redirect works well, but add the old image name into address.
Why? I don't need this.

What i'm get now:
www.mypage.lt/wp-content/default-5x5.jpg?file=/wp-content/my-image-5x5.jpg

What i need:
www.mypage.lt/wp-content/default-5x5.jpg

Comment: That should have nothing to do with the `RedirectMatch` directive. More likely you have additional Rewriting in place, that’s responsible for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Redirect works well, but add the old image name into address. Why? I don't need this.

This is because you have wordpress rules which does internal routing (to an `index.php` file) and the rewrite rules belong to mod_rewrite, while the `RedirectMatch` directive belongs to mod_alias. These modules both get applied at different points in the URL-file mapping pipeline, thus both get applied, and you end up with a mangled redirect URL. You should stick to only mod_rewrite in this instance. Try adding these rules **before** your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/my-image-5x5.jpg /wp-content/default-5x5.jpg [L,R=301]
```